# Prevent preg_replace to mistaken integer for capture group

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

for a project i'm working on I need to change/update a PHP file.
This PHP file has a section 'last edit', which should contain the last updated datetime of the file.

The problem i'm having is that preg_replace misinterpets my capture group `$1` for `$12`
How can I solve this behaviour ?

```
<?php
$source = <<<'SOURCE'
<?php
/* 
    bla bla bla bla

    ================================================
    - Installer for Foo v.1.00           
    ================================================
        author      :   tommy
        created at  :   26-07-2014 15:45:39
        edited by   :   tommy
        last edit   :   26-07-2014 15:54:31
        remarques   :

    ===============================================*/


# IMPORTANT : Don't change closure name  
$func = function() {
    /* -- Do stuff here -- */

};
SOURCE;

function getLoggedInUser() {
    return 'LLama';
}

function updateFileInformation($code) {
        $pattern = '#({placeholder}.+:\s+)(.+)(\n)#mi';     

        $needles = [
            str_replace('{placeholder}', 'edited by', $pattern),
            str_replace('{placeholder}', 'last edit', $pattern),
        ];      
        $replacements = [
            '$1'.getLoggedInUser().'$3',
            '$1'.date('d-m-Y H:i:s').'$3',
        ];
        return preg_replace($needles, $replacements, $code);
}

echo updateFileInformation($source);
```

Expected output should be :

```
Last edit : 26-07-2014 16:07:15
```

Real output :

```
6-07-2014 16:07:15
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/6UncH3)

Comment: Don’t use regular expressions for stuff like this – put placeholders into your text and use `sprintf`, `strtr` or the like to populate the values.

Comment: How would I do that? The text behind `edited by` and `last edit` will change. This file is then stored as a PHP file and if someone needs to change it I load up the textarea with a `file_get_contents` from the stored file

Comment: @DarkBee May i know the input.

Comment: @AvinashRaj The input? I don't quite get what U are asking

Comment: you put `{placeholder}` in the regex, but there isn't a string like that i your input `$source`. Sorry i don't know about placeholders.

Comment: The source is defined with a `heredoc` in `$source` :) $sourc = '<?php ....'. The two <?php are prolly confusing U a bit

Comment: @DarkBee How about this http://regex101.com/r/tJ0yG2/6 ?

Comment: The regex is capturing just fine. Its the replace that is failing. See demo, PHP thinks i want capture group `$12` but I want capture group `$1`

Comment: @DarkBee: just protect the backreferences in your replacement text, e.g. use `${1}` instead of `$1`.

Comment: @ntd : Indeed that works. Put it as an answer if U like. I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just protect the backreferences in your replacement text, e.g. use `${1}` instead of `$1`.